# Does there exist a complete implementation of the Risch algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, integration, computer-algebra, differential-algebra

Is there a generally available (commercial or not) complete implementation of the Risch algorithm for determining whether an elementary function has an elementary antiderivative?

The [Wikipedia article on symbolic integration](https://web.archive.org/web/20200729023245/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_integration) claims that the general case of the Risch algorithm was solved and implemented in Axiom by Manuel Bronstein, and an [answer to another MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/171979/1) says the same thing.  However, I have some doubts, based on the following [comment by Manuel Bronstein himself](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math.symbolic/YXlaU8WA2JI/1w1MxrSpm6IJ) on the USENET newsgroup `sci.math.symbolic` on September 5, 2003:

> If Axiom returns an unevaluated integral,
> then
> it has proven that no elementary antiderivative exists. There are
> however
> some cases where Axiom can return an error message saying that you've
> hit
> an unimplemented branch of the algorithm, in which case it cannot
> conclude.
> So Richard was right in pointing out that the Risch algorithm is not
> fully implemented there either. Axiom is unique in making the difference
> between unimplemented branches and proofs of non-integrability, and also
> in actually proving the algebraic independence of the building blocks
> of the integrand before concluding nonintegrability (others typically
> assume this independence after performing some heuristic dependence
> checking).

Bronstein unfortunately [passed away on June 6, 2005](https://web.archive.org/web/20090709152940/http://www.ccas.ru/sabramov/ps/PCS56.pdf).  It is possible that he completed the implementation before he died, but I haven't been able to confirm that.  I do know that Bronstein never managed to finish his intended book on the integration of algebraic functions. [**EDIT:** As a further
check, I emailed Barry Trager. He confirmed that the implementation that
he and Bronstein worked on was not complete. He did not know much about
other implementations but was not aware of any complete implementations.]

I have access to Maple 2018, and it doesn't seem to have a complete implementation either. A useful test case is the following integral, taken from the (apparently unpublished) paper [Trager's algorithm for the integration of algebraic functions revisited](https://web.archive.org/web/20240227205128/https://bpb-us-e1.wpmucdn.com/sites.psu.edu/dist/d/34699/files/2016/12/IntegrationOnCurves-2hhuby8.pdf) by Daniel Schultz:
$$\int \frac{29x^2+18x-3}{\sqrt{x^6+4x^5+6x^4-12x^3+33x^2-16x}}\,dx$$
Schultz explicitly provides an elementary antiderivative in his paper, but Maple 2018 returns the integral unevaluated.

Comment: I thought Risch's algorithm was contigent on having the ability to perform zero-testing that isn't quite algorithmically justified?

Comment: @AndrejBauer : It does assume that zero-recognition can be performed in the underlying field of constants. But if your initial expression involves only algebraic numbers (satisfying known polynomial equations with integer coefficients) then there is an algorithm for zero-recognition, that is conjectural only in the sense that the guarantee that it terminates depends on Schanuel's conjecture. When the algorithm terminates, it gives the right answer, and since Schanuel's conjecture is surely true, the algorithm will always terminate. See Richardson's paper on the elementary constant problem.

Comment: Bottom line is, zero-recognition of constants isn't the sticking point in practice. I'd be happy to see an implementation whose only "gap" is zero-recognition of constants (and of course the constraints imposed by finite time and memory).

Comment: Landau required students who wanted to study with him to be able to compute every indefinite integral that can be computed in elementary functions. Perhaps his students had the Risch code built into their synapses.

Comment: @TimothyChow does Risch only require zero-recognition of constants? I thought it also requires zero-recogniton of elementary functions.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold : I could be missing some subtlety but I think that's right. Just now I took a quick look at [Risch's original paper](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1970-12454-5) and it seems to me that the base case of the induction requires only zero-recognition of constants.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No computer algebra system implements a complete decision process for the integration of mixed transcendental and algebraic functions.

The integral from the excellent paper of Schultz may be solved by Maple if you convert the integrand to RootOf notation (Why this is not done internally in Maple is an interesting question?)

```
int(convert((29*x^2+18*x-3)/(x^6+4*x^5+6*x^4-12*x^3+33*x^2-16*x)^(1/2),RootOf),x);
```

My experiments suggest Maple has the best implementation of the Risch-Trager-Bronstein algorithm for the integration of purely algebraic integrals in terms of elementary functions (ref: table 1, section 3 of Sam Blake, *A Simple Method for Computing Some Pseudo-Elliptic Integrals in Terms of Elementary Functions*, arXiv:[2004.04910](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.04910)). However, Maple's implementation does not integrate expressions containing parameters or nested radicals (both of which has some support in AXIOM and FriCAS).

It would seem that some significant progress has been made in computing the logarithmic part of a mixed transcendental-algebraic integral by Miller [1]. Though, as far as I know, no computer algebra system has implemented his algorithm. It is also not clear if Miller's algorithm can deal with parameters, for example, the Risch-Trager-Bronstein algorithm has difficulties with the following pseudo-elliptic integral

$$\int\frac{\left(p x^2-q\right) \left(p x^2-x+q\right)dx}{x \left(p x^2+2 x+q\right) \sqrt{2 p^2x^4+2 p x^3+(4 p q+1) x^2+2 q x+2 q^2}} = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log (x) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log \left(\sqrt{2} y +2 p x^2+x+2q\right) - \frac{3}{\sqrt{5}}\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{5} y}{3 p x^2+3 q+x}\right),$$
where $y=\sqrt{2 p^2 x^4+2 p x^3+(4 pq+1)x^2+2 q x+2 q^2}$. My heuristic in the [previously-linked paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.04910.pdf) computes this integral quickly with the substitution $u=\frac{px^2+q}{p x}$.

In regards to the mixed algebraic-transcendental case of the Risch-Trager-Bronstein algorithm, an integral which cannot be solved with Maple, Mathematica, AXIOM or FriCAS (and possibly other CAS) is

$$\int \frac{\left(\sqrt{x}+1\right) \left(e^{2x \sqrt{x}} -a\right) \sqrt{a^2+2 a x e^{2 \sqrt{x}} +cx e^{2 \sqrt{x}} +x^2 e^{4 \sqrt{x}}}}{x \sqrt{x}e^{\sqrt{x}} \left(a+x e^{2 \sqrt{x}} \right)} dx.$$

This integral is interesting as it returns two distinct messages from AXIOM and FriCAS suggesting their respective implementations are incomplete. FriCAS returns

```
(1) -> integrate(((-a+exp(2*x^(1/2))*x)*x^(-3/2)*(1+x^(1/2))*(a^2+2*a*exp(2*x^(1/2))*x+c*exp(2*x^(1/2))*x+exp(4*x^(1/2))*x^2)^(1/2))/(exp(x^(1/2))*(a+exp(2*x^(1/2))*x)),x)
                                                                                                        
   >> Error detected within library code:                                                               
   integrate: implementation incomplete (has polynomial part)
```

While AXIOM returns

```
(1) -> integrate(((-a+exp(2*x^(1/2))*x)*x^(-3/2)*(1+x^(1/2))*(a^2+2*a*exp(2*x^(1/2))*x+c*exp(2*x^(1/2))*x+exp(4*x^(1/2))*x^2)^(1/2))/(exp(x^(1/2))*(a+exp(2*x^(1/2))*x)),x)
                                                                                                        
   >> Error detected within library code:
   integrate: implementation incomplete (constant residues)
```

[1] Miller, B. (2012). “[On the Integration of Elementary Functions: Computing the Logarithmic Part](http://hdl.handle.net/2346/45299)”. Thesis (Ph.D.) Texas Tech University, Dept. of Mathematics and Statistics.

Comment: actually, fricas does this integral in a second

Comment: @MartinRubey, I didn't mean to imply that AXIOM and/or FriCAS could not compute this integral. Here's an example which Maple and AXIOM can compute and FriCAS claims is not elementary:

int(convert(((-1+3*x^4)*(1+x+2*x^4+x^5+x^8)^(1/2))/(x^2*(4+x+4*x^4)),RootOf),x);

Comment: To be fair, here's one which may be computed with FriCAS and AXIOM, but returns an error in Maple: 
int(convert((x^3+1)*(x^6-x^3-2)^(1/2)/x^4/(x^6-2*x^3-1),RootOf),x);

Comment: I cannot verify you claim that fricas returns the integral above unevaluated.  I get: ${-{x \ {\log \left( {{{-{2 \ {\sqrt {{{{x} ^ {8}}+{{x} ^ {5}}+{2 \ {{x} ^ {4}}}+x+1}}}}+{2 \ {{x} ^ {4}}}+x+2} \over x}} \right)}} -{x \ {\sqrt {3}} \ {\arctan \left( {{{{\left( {2 \ {{x} ^ {4}}} -x+2 \right)} \ {\sqrt {3}}} \over {6 \ {\sqrt {{{{x} ^ {8}}+{{x} ^ {5}}+{2 \ {{x} ^ {4}}}+x+1}}}}}} \right)}}+{4 \ {\sqrt {{{{x} ^ {8}}+{{x} ^ {5}}+{2 \ {{ x} ^ {4}}}+x+1}}}}} \over {{16} \ x} $ within a second, at least with the current version from git.

Comment: @MartinRubey Looks like the dev version of FriCAS has fixed this example. I ran it on 1.3.6.

Comment: It might be interesting to re-run your testsuite.  If this was a bug, then possibly it affected also other examples.

Comment: Extremely informative response...thanks! I am wondering if there is some kind of "roadmap" that delineates the main challenges that stand in the way of a complete implementation. The Fricas "Risch Implementation Status" page mentioned by Dima Pasechnik is a start but is vague about some important details. If there were a clearly mapped-out plan of attack, perhaps it would attract more researchers to the area, and the challenges could be knocked off one by one.

Comment: @TimothyChow I'm afraid the problem is that there is essentially one person working on this, which is Waldek Hebisch.  He is brilliant, though.

Comment: The problem on the implementation part is that Fricas is  a very complex and somewhat esoteric system,  the commitment required from a potential contributor is quite big.

Comment: @TimothyChow, one of the issues is even if a _complete_ implementation was made, many integrals take an inordinate amount of time to compute. My heuristic method (referenced in the answer) quickly computes many integrals that take hours to return an answer in FriCAS/AXIOM.

Comment: @TimothyChow, in terms of your roadmap - here's an example which returns a long-standing error in AXIOM/FriCAS "Error detected within library code: integrate: implementation incomplete (residue poly has multiple non-linear factors)"

`integrate(((4+x^6)*(-4+x^4+2*x^6)*(32-14*x^4-32*x^6-4*x^8+7*x^10+8*x^12)^(1/2))/(x^9*(-2+x^6)),x)` 

Maple computes this integral 

`int(convert(((4+x^6)*(-4+x^4+2*x^6)*(32-14*x^4-32*x^6-4*x^8+7*x^10+8*x^12)^(1/2))/(x^9*(-2+x^6)),RootOf),x);`

and my heuristic quickly recognises that...

Comment: ... the substitution $u=\frac{x^6-2}{x^4}$, reduces the integral to 
$$\int \frac{\left(x^6+4\right) \left(2 x^6+x^4-4\right) \sqrt{8
   x^{12}+7 x^{10}-4 x^8-32 x^6-14 x^4+32}}{x^9
   \left(x^6-2\right)} dx = \int  \frac{(2 u+1) \sqrt{8 u^2+7 u-4}}{2 u} du.$$

Comment: Just for the record: the very first integral in your answer, involving the two parameters, is done by the development version of FriCAS (in about 15 minutes on my computer), whereas the other branches are still unimplemented.

Answer (score 26):

[Fricas](http://fricas.sourceforge.net/), an open-source clone of Axiom, implements a considerable chunk of Risch, see
http://fricas-wiki.math.uni.wroc.pl/RischImplementationStatus

Fricas is also available as a optional package of [SageMath](https://sagemath.org) open-source system.

Edit: here how it goes in SageMath with Fricas as backend.

---

```
sage: r=integrate((29*x^2+18*x-3)/(x^6+4*x^5+6*x^4-12*x^3+33*x^2-16*x)^(1/2),x,algorithm="fricas")                                                                                                                                     
sage: r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
log(x^29 + 40*x^28 + 776*x^27 + 9648*x^26 + 85820*x^25 + 578480*x^24 + 3058536*x^23 + 12979632*x^22 + 45004902*x^21 + 129708992*x^20 + 317208072*x^19 + 675607056*x^18 + 1288213884*x^17 + 2238714832*x^16 + 3548250712*x^15 + 5097069328*x^14 + 6677210721*x^13 + 8106250392*x^12 + 9056612528*x^11 + 8991685504*x^10 + 7944578304*x^9 + 6614046720*x^8 + 4834279424*x^7 + 2374631424*x^6 + 916848640*x^5 + 638582784*x^4 - 279969792*x^3 - 528482304*x^2 + (x^26 + 38*x^25 + 699*x^24 + 8220*x^23 + 68953*x^22 + 436794*x^21 + 2161755*x^20 + 8550024*x^19 + 27506475*x^18 + 73265978*x^17 + 165196041*x^16 + 324386076*x^15 + 570906027*x^14 + 914354726*x^13 + 1326830817*x^12 + 1731692416*x^11 + 2055647184*x^10 + 2257532160*x^9 + 2246693120*x^8 + 1939619840*x^7 + 1494073344*x^6 + 1097859072*x^5 + 640024576*x^4 + 207618048*x^3 + 95420416*x^2 + 50331648*x - 50331648)*sqrt(x^6 + 4*x^5 + 6*x^4 - 12*x^3 + 33*x^2 - 16*x) + 150994944*x - 134217728)
```